# How can I navigate between pages inside a PhoneGap application?

Tags: iphone, android, cordova

I am newbie with PhoneGap and I'm a little bit lost.
I have installed and run the example app and it works ok. Now I want to change a little the default app.
I want a button or link to change from the current page/view to another I have in the "www" folder. If I use "..." it opens Safari.

How can I navigate between views/pages inside a PhoneGap application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use mobile web UI frameworks that work on top of PhoneGap like [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) or [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).  They have view stacks already integrated and are easy to work with.

Or you could do what I do and create your own view stack from scratch, which isn't nearly as hard as it may sound.  I use PhoneGap along with [xuijs](http://xuijs.com/) to transition full screen, fixed position divs that represent "views".

Be sure to use CSS3 transitions instead of javascript animation when possible and they will perform much better.

Comment: That is!! Thank you very much, I will try with jQuery Mobile.